# HTTP headers for public Assets in play framework

Tags: playframework, http-headers, response-headers

How to set headers for public Assets in play framework? **Assets** are like **javascript**, **css** and **images** files. How to set **X-Content-Type-Options, X-XSS-Protection,and X-Frame-Options** headers to these files? Where to set? I need centralize solution so that it will be applicable for all JS, CSS, and images files.

For all web pages I have added these headers but for public Assets ZAP tool is giving an alert that these headers are missing. So how to do this?

Comment: Help me out on this plz

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the headers to all requests you can create a filter and add it to your `Global` object.

```
object Global extends WithFilters(YourFilterHere(), new GzipFilter(), etc...) with GlobalSettings {
  // onStart, onStop etc...
}
```

See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SecurityHeaders for details.